# Azure Automation: Onboarding DSC Node: "vmname, The entity was not found."

Tags: powershell, azure, dsc, azure-automation

I'm trying to onboard a VM to Azure Automation DSC using the `Register-AzureRmAutomationDSCNode` cmdlet as recommended [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding) for non-classic vm's. The DSC nodeconfiguration has been both imported and compiled in Azure Automation.

Here is my code:

```
$AutomationAccountName = "PersistentAutomationAccount"
$VMName = "VM1" 
$AutomationResourceGroup = "PersistantResources" 
$VMResourceGroup = "AutomatingAutomation2"
$NodeConfigurationName = "HelloWorldDSC.localhost"
Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode -AutomationAccountName $AutomationAccountName -AzureVMName $VMName -ResourceGroupName $AutomationResourceGroup -AzureVMResourceGroup $VMResourceGroup -NodeConfigurationName $NodeConfigurationName
```

But I'm getting the following error which I can't find an explanation for:

```
New-AzureRmResourceGroupDeployment : 10:56:57 AM - Resource 

Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions 'VM1/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC' failed with message '{
  "error": {
    "code": "NotFound",
    "target": "vmName",
    "message": "The entity was not found."
  }
}'
```

The VM name is correct, it exists, the resourcesgroup names are correct, so what is not being found?  I thought maybe the VM needed an extension preinstalled, but according to an Azure rep it's Automation's job to install the dsc agent/extension once the node is onboarded.

Comment: does this happen only to this particular vm? also, I've been using it without `-AzureVMResourceGroup `

Comment: I'll check. I needed that parameter because my automation account and vm are in two different resource groups.

Comment: you should probably look at the activity monitor and try to figure out what is getting passed to the dsc extension provisioning

Comment: I created a new vm and targeted it and the same error happens.  
I don't know how to make sense of that JSON, what elements (objects) am I looking for in there?

Comment: well, try to find the name\id of the vm that is being acted upon, also you might want to run the `Register-AzureRmAutomationDscNode` with the `-debug` switch and see what is going on there

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is your VM in a different region from your automation account? If so, have you tried adding the AzureVMLocation variable and including the VM region?

Comment: That was it.  Thanks!  So Azure needs three peices to find a specific VM?  Region, Resource Group, and VM Name (and subscription perhaps)?  I guess I hadn't thought that Azure discriminates by region.

Comment: Yes, you always need the VM Name, and then for simplification the region and resource group are assumed to be the same as the Azure Automation account. However, if they are different they have to be specified since Azure discriminates based on both. There currently is not support for adding a VM from a different subscription as a DSC node, but if you needed to, you could probably onboard it as an on premise machine using the documentation here (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/automation-dsc-onboarding).

Comment: Thanks, this helped me understand my problem. I experienced the same error, when trying to onboard through an ARM template rather than the PowerShell cmdlet. I was setting the "location" property to match the Azure Automation account, rather than the VM the extension was being applied to.

Comment: @JennyHunter! Woaw this helped me a lot!